# Inner product of two continuous maps is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let f,g be continuous maps of *S* in $\mathbb{R}^n$, to $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show the inner product h(x) = $\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle$ is continuous.

My attempt:
Since f,g are continuous, their product is a continuous mapping, so for $\epsilon \gt 0\: t.e\:  \delta \gt 0$ such that $\parallel x - a\parallel \lt \delta $ implies $\parallel \langle f(x),g(x)\rangle - \langle f(a)g(a)\rangle \parallel \le\parallel f(x)g(x) - f(a)g(a)\parallel \lt \epsilon$ by schwartz inequality.

Comment: What is $f(x)g(x)$ is the codomain of $f$ and $g$ is both $ℝ^m$? Or did I misunderstand you? What do you mean by "continuous maps of $S$ in $ℝ^n$, with $ℝ^m$", anyway?

Comment: I think the question mean continuous function from Rn to Rm, the phraseology in the book is a bit weird i agree

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(Adjust $n$, $m$ as appropriate, the question is a little ambiguous.)

The map $\phi: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ (or complex, if it suits) defined by $\phi(x,y) = \langle x , y \rangle $ is continuous since 
\begin{eqnarray}
|\phi(x,y) - \phi(x',y')| &=& |\phi(x,y) - \phi(x,y') + \phi(x,y') - \phi(x',y')| \\
& \leq & |\phi(x,y) - \phi(x,y')| + |\phi(x,y') - \phi(x',y')| \\
& \leq & \|x\| \|y-y'\| + \|y'\| \|x-x'\|
\end{eqnarray}
Hence if $\max(\|x-x'\|,\|y-y'\|) \leq 1$, then $|\phi(x,y) - \phi(x',y')| \leq \max(\|x\|,\|y\|+1)(\|y-y'\| + \|x-x'\|)$. Now choose $\epsilon>0$, then if $\max(\|x-x'\|,\|y-y'\|) < \frac{1}{2\max(\|x\|,\|y\|+1)}\epsilon$ (and $\leq 1$, of course), you have $|\phi(x,y) - \phi(x',y')| < \epsilon$.

Since $\phi$ is continuous, and the map $\eta:S \to \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $\eta(x) = (f(x),g(x))$ is continuous, it follows that the composition $\phi \circ \eta$ is continuous.

Comment: will it still hold for a range Rm, m>=1?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, the inner product takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. What values are in $\mathbb{R}^m$?

Comment: I don't understand why you can have that inequality for the max of the 'distance' between points... could you please elaborate a bit more? thanks ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. We have $\|y'\| \le \|y\| + \|y-y'\| \le \|y\|+1$. Is that what you were asking about?

Comment: Basically from the word 'Hence' forward, I find it hard to follow your reasoning. Would you please mind helping me? Where did you use the content your last comment in your answer?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: One way to answer the question is to show that the map $\phi$ (the inner product) is continuous and the map $\eta$ (just the map from $x$ to the pair $(f(x),g(x))$ are continuous. Then the composition (which is what the OP asked about) is continuous.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea. So, I want to show $\phi$ (the inner product) is continuous at (fixed) $(x,y)$. In particular, I need to find a neighbourhood of $(x,y)$ such that $|\phi(x,y) - \phi(x',y')| $ is small for $(x',y')$ in the neighbourhood of $(x,y)$. I can always assume the neighbourhood is smaller that a given size, that is why I assume that $\max(\|x-x'\|,\|x-y'\|) \le 1$. The eventual neighbourhood that shows continuity will be contained in this neighbourhood.

Comment: Ok. I think I get it now. Just one more question. Wouldn't just $||y-y'||\leq 1$ be enough, instead of the $max$ of both?

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: Yes it would. I just put it in as a neighbourhood restriction, mainly out of habit.

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.: It is a good question. I think 'standard' tricks like I did above can be very confusing unless one is aware that there is some arbitrariness/personal preference involved.

Comment: I appreciated your help. thanks ;)

Comment: @Anoldmaninthesea.:  Glad to help & thanks for raising my awareness :-).